# save button functionality in java

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, dao

I have created a profile page which displays the details of logged in user. An edit button is provided which takes me to different jsp. In this jsp, on editing the details, a Save button is provided.. Now on changing any value, how do i save the complete form. what is the functionality fir save ? I am using DAO in order to display the values from database.

Comment: this is not very clear question. you should explain your problem better i think. on the view layer, after click save button post a json which hold details and then on the controller layer parse and map it to your model and then persist it with your dao layer.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 0):

Well...

1 DAO: create DAO that have add/get/update/delete methods.

2 Create form in jsp with fields of user.

```
<form name="userEditForm" method="post" action="...">
    <input type="text" name="userName" value="..."/>
</form>
```

3 Create Servlet/Controller (Spring) that process you post request to specified address in form action.

4 Get form data from request and pass it to DAO to add/update used:

```
String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
User user = new User();
user.setName(userName);
userDao.update(user);
```

This is common flow.